# Converting date to string in template

Tags: python, regex, django

I want to convert data to string in template (To simplify the url)
For this i do following :

My URLs.py:

```
url(r'^export/range/csv/(?P<start_date>\d+)/(?P<end_date>\d+)/$', views.export_payment_range_csv, name="export_payment_range_csv"),
```

My link in template:

```
  <li><a href="{% url 'export_payment_range_csv'
  start_date=start_date.string  end_date=end_date.string %}">CSV for
  current range payments</a>
```

on template side start_date and end_date are in format of date and not string.

but getting

> NoReverseMatch at /payment/list/range/ Reverse for
>   'export_payment_range_csv' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments
>   '{u'start_date': '', u'end_date': ''}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried:
>   ['condition/export/range/csv/(?P\d+)/(?P\d+)/$',
>   'payment/export/range/csv/(?P\d+)/(?P\d+)/$']

What I do wrong?

UPDATE:

When I do not do conversion on the template side  error I am getting:

> NoReverseMatch at /payment/list/range/ Reverse for
>   'export_payment_range_csv' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments
>   '{u'start_date': datetime.date(2016, 2, 1), u'end_date':
>   datetime.date(2016, 12, 31)}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried:
>   ['condition/export/range/csv/(?P\d+)/(?P\d+)/$',
>   'payment/export/range/csv/(?P\d+)/(?P\d+)/$']

Comment: What made you think that `.string` was a valid thing to do on datetimes? And note that even if you fixed that, a stringified date still wouldn't match a `\d+` regex.

Comment: Thank you. so what is my way out? I should work on the regular expression in urls.py or...?

Comment: I would consider using unix timestamps since they're easily parsed. Of course, you could also choose a datetime format and stick with it. https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 1):

Because `\d` is a digit, and the type that you're trying to return is not even 
close to that.

Assuming that the dates are *actually* dates, you can do this:

```
start_date=start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Which will give you something like `2010-08-14`.
 The regex for a date in that form would be `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}` (though that's not technically validating the date).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I would update the regex in your URL to the following:

```
r'^export/range/csv/(?P<start_date>[-\d]+)/(?P<end_date>[-\d]+)/$
```

In the templatesystem there isn't a `.string`-method you can use (unless you have created your own templatefilter). So to get your date-objects to be converted to strings, you can use Django's buildin templatefilter `.date`. To do that, use the following for generating your url in the template:

```
{% url 'export_payment_range_csv' start_date=start_date|date:"Y-m-d" end_date=end_date|date:"Y-m-d" %}
```

This will create date-strings of the format YYYY-MM-DD. See [Django's date-docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#date).

Answer (score 0):

I moved date to string in my regex

```
  url(r'^export/range/csv/(?P<start_date>\S+)/(?P<end_date>\S+)/$', views.export_payment_range_csv, name="export_payment_range_csv"),
```

and sending as it is the date format from template

```
<li><a href="{% url 'export_payment_range_csv' start_date=start_date end_date=end_date %}">CSV for current range payments</a>
```

It works